# Unit test IBackgroundJobClient.Schedule

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, hangfire

I am using Hangfire to schedule some jobs. All my jobs have a schedule date, so I'm using Schedule static extension method

```
public static string Schedule([NotNull] this IBackgroundJobClient client, [InstantHandle][NotNull] Expression<Action> methodCall, DateTimeOffset enqueueAt);
```

I want to unit test my methods, so that I can check that Hangfire is actually being triggered.

To do so, I've followed Hangfire's documentation on unit testing (https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-methods/writing-unit-tests.html) which suggests mocking `IBackgroundJobClient` and verifying on the only public Create method it has:

```
string Create([NotNull] Job job, [NotNull] IState state);
```

But I can see that for Schedule invocations, this is not being called, another overload that is not public is being called instead, so I get the following error:

```
Message: Moq.MockException : 
Expected invocation on the mock at least once, but was never performed: x => x.Create(It.IsAny<job>(), It.IsAny<enqueuedstate>())
No setups configured.

Performed invocations: 
IBackgroundJobClient.Create(JobService.TaskFunction, ScheduledState)
```

Nevertheless, I've made an attempt with `Enqueue` method, and that seems to work with the mock. But I need to use `Schedule`.

Another option would be to assert on the overload it is actually calling

```
public static string Create([NotNull] this IBackgroundJobClient client, [InstantHandle][NotNull] Expression<Action> methodCall, [NotNull] IState state);
```

But since it's an extension method, that's not a valid approach for Moq.

`Message: System.NotSupportedException : Invalid verify on an extension method: x => x.Create(It.IsAny<Expression<Action>>(), It.IsAny<EnqueuedState>())`

So how can I unit test Hangfire for `Schedule` method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The example you refer to uses different extension method which at the end calls different `IBackgroundJobClient` method, [github](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/blob/master/src/Hangfire.Core/BackgroundJobClientExtensions.cs#L44). The following method has been invoked:

```
client.Create(Expression<Action> methodCall, new EnqueuedState());
```

It perfectly fits the `Verify` within the example.

---

On the other hand, your are calling `Schedule` method, [github](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/blob/master/src/Hangfire.Core/BackgroundJobClientExtensions.cs#L156). `Schedule` method at the end invokes the following:

```
client.Create(Expression<Action> methodCall, new ScheduledState(enqueueAt.UtcDateTime))
```

Which is also an expression method, so you need to dive deeper one more level where actual `interface` method has been called:

```
string Create([NotNull] Job job, [NotNull] IState state);
```

As you can see from the error itself your expectation doesn't match with the actual invocation:

```
Performed invocations: 
IBackgroundJobClient.Create(JobService.TaskFunction, ScheduledState)
```

Your assert should be something like this:

```
// Assert
client.Verify(x => x.Create(
    It.IsAny<Job>(), //you could as in example check actual method name
    It.IsAny<IState>()); //you could check actual offset
```

Comment: That's not a possible assert... since that Create overload is an extension method. I had already tried that. I'll update my post

Comment: @keycad you are right, then just one level deeper :), I updated

Comment: So the problem was with my `IsAny<EnqueuedState>`, I wasn't using the proper interface, thank you :)